# Struct inside struct in doubly linked list

Tags: c, struct, linked-list

I want to create a doubly linked list. In node, this datas must be in: name, lastname, department, grade.
My structs are,

```
typedef struct DATA{
    long Number;
    char name[30],lastname[30],department[50];
    int grade;
}DATA;

struct DATA* data;
typedef struct node{
    DATA data;
    struct node* next;
    struct node* prev;
}node;

struct node* start=NULL;
```

I'm trying to reach with

```
struct node* CreateNode(int number, char name1[30], char lastname1[30], char department1[50])
{
    struct node* newNode = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    data->Number=number;
    data->name[30]=name1[30];
    data->lastname[30]=lastname1[30];
    data->department[50]=department1[50];
    newNode->next=NULL;
    newNode->prev=NULL;
    return newNode;
}

void SonaEkleme(int number, char name1[30], char lastname1[30], char department1[50])
{
    struct node* addData = CreateNode(number, name1, lastname1, department1);

    if (start==NULL) 
    {
        start=addData;
    }
    else
    {
        struct node* temp=start;
        while(temp->next!=NULL)
        {
            temp=temp->next;
         }
         addData->prev=temp;
         temp->next=addData;
    } 
}
```

But it can't add a new node. How can I add one more data in doubly linked list node?

Comment: You need to spend some time better understanding how arrays work in C. Your syntax is wrong on it's assumption, and your copying *one* char for each of those assignments, and even then, they're wrong (out of bounds).

Comment: In addition to whozcraig's comment data->name[30]=name1[30]; is UB ... and will likely crash.  Your array size is 30.  That means you have elements 0-29

Answer (score 0):

I think you are mixing up contents of temp with temp itself!

```
*temp=temp->next;
```